# what is this meaning of "could"?

Tags: modal-verbs, sequence-of-tenses, could-modal

> A: Your French is horrible.
> B: Oh really? Then, seems like I've been deceiving myself into thinking that I could speak it when I actually couldn't.

This "could" is the result of the sequence of tenses?

Answer (score 1):

Here, "could" functions as the past form of "can".

That sentence, however, is unnatural, and arguably ungrammatical.

It would be much better either to use "***can***" rather than "could" since present perfect continuous has a present meaning, or to use almost any past tense, like:

- *...I **deceived** myself...*
- *...I **was deceiving** myself...*
- *...I **had been deceiving** myself...*
- *...I **had deceived** myself...*

Answer (score 1):

My intuition is that this is "could" as the *subjunctive* - it is referring to something that it is possible, but not true.

Compare "if I could speak French, that would be good".

Answer (score 0):

I thought I **could speak it** [when I tried to] but I can't. [now]

That's fine.

NYT

She added: “I **thought** I could win. I didn’t expect to win.”

The New Yorker

“I really **got** lost. And I didn’t have my truck. I **thought I could** hitchhike back home.

[ludwig.guru examples from the press_spoken English](https://ludwig.guru/s/i+thought+i+could)

I have been deceiving myself into thinking I could [at some point in the past].
I have been deceiving myself into thinking I can. [now].

could means: **was able to** in these examples, a past tense.